# rspec stack trace on autotest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, autotest

I'm just getting into autotest and i have the following problem.

How do I get autotest to print stack traces on errors.
If i run "rake spec" i get output

```
  4) Transaction should get date with poor form
 Failure/Error: transaction = Transaction.build_from_email(@email)
 NoMethodError:
   private method `gsub' called for 112:Fixnum
 # ./app/models/transaction.rb:46:in `build_from_email'
 # ./spec/models/transaction_spec.rb:104
```

but i get the following with autotest

```
  4) Transaction should get date with poor form
 Failure/Error: transaction = Transaction.build_from_email(@email)
 NoMethodError:
   private method `gsub' called for 112:Fixnum
```

Would just be alot easier to find where the error is.

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using RSpec 2 you can add a file called `.rspec` in the project root with this content:

```
--backtrace
```

RSpec will read this file when it's run, whether it's through Rake or Autotest.

Comment: is there any way to run this on-demand, for the first failing test, from the guard console?